# Instruments (Leaks/Activity Monitor/Time Profiler etc.) won't start - what's going on?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments, monitor

I'm sorry if this question was somewhere here already, but I'm struggling with this problem for hours with no results. Long story short - I have a fresh installation of Xcode (version 3.2.5 64bit) and when I try to run my app with a performance tool (let's say Leaks), Instruments just crash, no matter which tool I choose. As I'm a beginner when it comes to Xcode I have no clue what's wrong. Please find the crash report below:

> Process:         Instruments [4033]
>   Path:
>   /Developer/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments
>   Identifier:      com.apple.Instruments
>   Version:         2.7 (3017) Build
>   Info:      Instruments-30170000~6 Code
>   Type:       X86-64 (Native) Parent
>   Process:  launchd [172]
>
> Date/Time:       2011-03-29
>   19:43:52.996 +0100 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J3250) Report
>   Version:  6
>
> Interval Since Last Report:
>   118589 sec Crashes Since Last Report: 
>   14 Per-App Interval Since Last Report:
>   24 sec Per-App Crashes Since Last
>   Report:   5 Anonymous UUID:
>   5934F52C-EF00-40F1-A0B4-17D52FA623F1
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT
>   (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
>   Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.main-thread
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Symbol not
>   found:
>   _CSSymbolicatorCreateWithMachKernel   Referenced from:
>   /Developer/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../Library/PrivateFrameworks//InstrumentsPlugIn.framework/Versions/A/InstrumentsPlugIn
>   Expected in:
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication

Has anyone experienced something like this before or knows how to fix it? I hope I've formulated my problem descriptively enough. I'd appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with xcode4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of fruitless struggle I have just updated my Xcode to version 4 and everything works perfectly fine. I still have no idea what was wrong with my previous installation, but since my Instruments work now, I won't investigate in any longer.